# How to data-bind HTML attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-binding, attributes

I need to binding data attribute with jQuery

```
<div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-blue" data-percent="name" ><span class="percent">{{name}}%</span></div>
```

I need to bind the "name" value with jQuery.
How can I do it in javascript.
Please help.

I need to set the "name" value in JS with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but assuming you have no control over mark-up.

```
<div class="easypiechart" id="easypiechart-blue" data-percent="name" >
    <span class="percent">
        {{name}}%
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var el = document.getElementById(“easypiechart-blue”)

el.data.percent = your val here;
```

Comment: It's not working. I want to turn [ data-percent="name" ] to [ data-percent="some value"]